# Proving that $h$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $h:S^1\times S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is given by $h(u, v, w)=(u, v^2, w^7)$. I want to show that $h$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

My thought is this: Suppose for contradiction, we assume that $h$ is a homotopy equivalence. Then $h_\ast$ must be an isomorphism. But since $h$ is not injective, it is not an isomorphism, therefore our assumption was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a covering map with $\tilde{X}$ connected. Then $p_*\pi_1(\tilde{X},x_0)\subseteq \pi_1(X,\pi(x_0))$ is a subgroup of index $p^{-1}(p(x_0))$. In particular, a covering map $\pi$ with connected covering space induces and epimorphism of fundamental groups if and only if $p^{-1}(p(x_0)) = \{x_0\}$.

Now your $h$ is a covering with a connected covering space, but has fibers of cardinality $2\cdot 7 = 14$ or something like that. Hence $h_*$ is not surjective and thus $h$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use covering spaces, use that the fundamental group of the three-fold product is the product of the fundamental groups, and check that the induced map is of the form $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a,2b,7c)$. This is not an isomorphism of groups.